# How to use svg in Vue standalone script without build step

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm trying to use Vue as a standalone script in an HTML file, but it's causing my inline svg icons to just become solid filled squares. I've tried both Vue 2 and Vue 3 as standalone scripts and both give the same behavior.

Although I've found solutions to Vue's svg issues that involve webpack loader configuration, I'm looking for a way to resovle the svg issues without any build step and only using Vue as a standalone script.

Note that the icon svg is copied directly from [Carbon Design Icons](https://carbondesignsystem.com/guidelines/icons/library/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      {{message}}
      <svg
        id="icon"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="32"
        height="32"
        viewBox="0 0 32 32"
      >
        <defs>
          <style>
            .cls-1 {
              fill: none;
            }
          </style>
        </defs>
        <path
          d="M16,8a5,5,0,1,0,5,5A5,5,0,0,0,16,8Zm0,8a3,3,0,1,1,3-3A3.0034,3.0034,0,0,1,16,16Z"
        />
        <path
          d="M16,2A14,14,0,1,0,30,16,14.0158,14.0158,0,0,0,16,2ZM10,26.3765V25a3.0033,3.0033,0,0,1,3-3h6a3.0033,3.0033,0,0,1,3,3v1.3765a11.8989,11.8989,0,0,1-12,0Zm13.9925-1.4507A5.0016,5.0016,0,0,0,19,20H13a5.0016,5.0016,0,0,0-4.9925,4.9258,12,12,0,1,1,15.985,0Z"
        />
        <rect
          id="_Transparent_Rectangle_"
          data-name="&lt;Transparent Rectangle&gt;"
          class="cls-1"
          width="32"
          height="32"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div>
      Icon outside of Vue
      <svg
        id="icon2"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="32"
        height="32"
        viewBox="0 0 32 32"
      >
        <defs>
          <style>
            .cls-2 {
              fill: none;
            }
          </style>
        </defs>
        <path
          d="M16,8a5,5,0,1,0,5,5A5,5,0,0,0,16,8Zm0,8a3,3,0,1,1,3-3A3.0034,3.0034,0,0,1,16,16Z"
        />
        <path
          d="M16,2A14,14,0,1,0,30,16,14.0158,14.0158,0,0,0,16,2ZM10,26.3765V25a3.0033,3.0033,0,0,1,3-3h6a3.0033,3.0033,0,0,1,3,3v1.3765a11.8989,11.8989,0,0,1-12,0Zm13.9925-1.4507A5.0016,5.0016,0,0,0,19,20H13a5.0016,5.0016,0,0,0-4.9925,4.9258,12,12,0,1,1,15.985,0Z"
        />
        <rect
          id="_Transparent_Rectangle_"
          data-name="&lt;Transparent Rectangle&gt;"
          class="cls-2"
          width="32"
          height="32"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    const { createApp } = Vue;

    createApp({
      data() {
        return {
          message: "Hello Vue!"
        };
      }
    }).mount("#app");
  </script>
</html>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-albattani-dxkvdt?file=/index.html:0-2221

Comment: Looks like a mistake to have style inside defs

Comment: The svg icon is copied directly from [Carbon Design Icons](https://carbondesignsystem.com/guidelines/icons/library/) and I updated the demo link to show the svg working properly when outside of the Vue mounted div

Comment: @EstusFlask I think you're right, looks like just moving the `.cls-1` class to a separate stylesheet may have resolved it

Comment: This means that the code that you copied was incorrect. There's no reason for <style> to be inside <defs>, I doubt that the spec guarantees it to work. That indiscrepancies like that work in some scenarios and not other ones is the reason why they need to be avoided. Yes, it should preferably be in separate stylesheet, inline <style> aren't very good in components

Answer (score 0):

change fill:none to fill:transparent

Answer (score 0):

This ended up not being a Vue issue, but a problem in the SVG code copied from an icon library. Estus Flask spotted that the style tag inside the SVG defs was likely the problem because it can cause inconsistent behavior in different scenarios, such as whether or not the inline svg style is contained within a div managed by Vue. The solution was moving that style class to a separate stylesheet.